# Confusion in PHP variables

Tags: php

Can we use the same variable name in PHP which is used to GET the data. Example: Get variable is `$_GET['V']`, now can I use `$V` variable for some other purpose or it will lead to ambiguity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$_GET['V']` and `$V` are in no way tied together and will occupy different memory. You can use both names.

If you change the default PHP configuration to enable `register_globals`, $V would be created as well as `$_GET['V']` if such a query string parameter existed, but you could still overwrite it and use it as a separate variable.

`register_globals` has not been enabled in the default PHP configuration for several years.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on [php.ini](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php) configurations file's register_globals settings

Comment: Before PHP 4.2 it was set to on, this feature has been set to off by default since PHP 4.2.0, is DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 6.0.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

You can use $V, just make sure register_globals is off, otherwise $V will be inicialized with the value of $_GET['V'] (but they will remain different vairables, so assigning value to $V won't affect $_GET['V'])

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if register_globals are off - and it should.